# session storage is not changing dependent box value dynamically on moble

Tags: mobile, drop-down-menu, triggers, touchscreen, session-storage

I have a webform with 2 select boxes (class name & student name ) getting their values from sql database whereas "student name" is dependent on "class name" value. I am saving my data on session storage to display after load. I am successful to get same data after load in "class name" , further i am adding **.trigger(change)** event to "class name " as student name dependent on changing value of class.

All above is working on desktop but not on mobile .i.e. all values are loading after page reload but .trigger(change) event is not working and hence cant select any other option on mobile.
Plz help me as i am stuck here since 3 weaks.
 My code is as follows:

```
<script>
// Run on page load
window.onload = function() {

        var sclass = sessionStorage.getItem('sclass');
        if (sclass !== null) $('#class').val(sclass).change();


window.onunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("sclass", $('#class').val());
</script>
```